# Ohr HaChaim on the Tribes' Individual Characteristics

Tags: shevatim-12-tribes

I remember that somewhere the Ohr HaChaim discusses the unique characteristics that each tribe possessed.  Does anyone know where in his commentary this can be found?  Thanks.